# How to identify relevant features in WEKA?

Tags: optimization, weka, feature-selection

I would like to perform feature analysis in WEKA. I have a data set of 8 features and 65 instances.

I would like to perform feature selection and optimization functionalities that are available for machine learning methods like SVM. 
For example in Weka I would like to know how I can display which of the features contribute best to the classification result.

I think that WEKA provides a nice graphical user interface and allows a very detailed analysis of the influence of single features. But I dont know how to use it. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

You have two options:

- You can perform *attribute selection using filters*. For instance you can use the `AttributeSelection` tab (or filter) with the search method `Ranker` and the attribute evaluation metric `InfoGainAttributeEval`. This way you get a ranked list of the most predictive features according to its Information Gain score. I have done this many times with good results. Sometimes it helps even to increase the accuracy of SVMs, which are known not to need (too much) of feature selection. You can try with other search methods in order to find subgroups of coupled predictors, and with other metrics.
- You can just *look at the coefficients in the SVM output*. For instance, in linear SVMs, the classifier is a polynomial like `a1.f1 + a2.f2 + ... + an.fn + fn+1 > 0`, being `ai` the attribute values for an instance, and `fi` the "weights" obtained in the SVM training algorithm. In consequence, those weights with values close to `0` represent attributes that do not count too much, thus being bad predictors; extreme weights (either positive or negative) represent good predictors.

Additionally, you can check the visualization options available for a particular classifier (e.g. J48 is a decision tree, the attribute used in the root test is for the best predictor). You can check the `AttributeSelection` tab visualization options as well.

Comment: thanks. I would like to try different classifier and not only SVM. So first would like to know which of the features contribute best to the classification result. Than reduce or make other combination of the featuresand with these new selected features try different classifier like Bayers, GP, Decision tree, SVM..

Comment: In this case, please follow the first option.

Comment: I thought the SVMAttributeEval metric and the Ranker serach method are the wright ones. SO whats the different between InfoGainAttributeEval and SVMAttributeEval?? Please can you explain?

Comment: `InfoGainAttributeEval` implements Information Gain, which is nearly an standard. It is an Information Theory metric that takes into consideration how the entropy (or separation) of the space points changes when using one attribute. A high score in Information Gain means it is easier to classify the points.

Regarding `SVMAttributeEval`, I copy from the doc: "it evaluates the worth of an attribute by using an SVM classifier. Attributes are ranked by the square of the weight assigned by the SVM." In other words, it roughly follows the second approach I dercribed above.

Comment: So in Weka I can perform first AttributeSelection tab (or filter) with the search method Ranker and the attribute evaluation metric InfoGainAttributeEval. Than I will get the ranked Features and with the best ranked Features can try different classifier in order to see if can improve the performance. Right?

Comment: Exact. You can filter the attributes according to their score, for instance keeping the top 10 features, or thosefeatures with Information Gain over `0.0`.

Comment: How about if I use SVMAtributSelection or any other method AtributSelection method and than use SVM as a classifier?Which Atribut Selection method best suit to SVM?

Comment: In principle, SVMAttributeEval should work well with SVMs. My experience in text mining is that using Information Gain quite often improves SVMs performance both in terms of accuracy and efficiency.

Please bear in mind that SVMs perfectly fit high-dimensional data so attribute selection may impact them in grey-area cases (for instance, one high weight attribute adds its weights, but ir is opposed by hundreds of low wiwight attributes that change the prediction - a borderliner point).

Comment: I dont have high-dimensional data. I have small data set. I tried both InfoGainAttributeEval and SVMAttributeEval method in atribut selection methog with LibSVM classifier in Weka and achieved much better results with SVMAttributeEval. Do you know why?

Comment: Well, high dimmensionality is not about the number of instances (rows) but features (columns). Most Text Categorization problems are high dimmensional, as we usually find many columns (different words) even in relatively small datasets. For instance, in the Reuters-21578 dataset (21,578 documents) you find more than 20,000 different words.

Regarding why `SVMAttributeEval` works better than `InfoGainAttributeEval`, I guess that it better fits your classifier (actually a SVM). However it always depends on the dataset, you may get different results in another dataset.